# Retrieving latitude & longitude values from database and mapping them using Google Map API in asp

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I have two fields `Hospital Name` & `City`. When I click on the `submit` button a new page will be shown displaying the location of the specified hospital. How can I achieve this task?

A `location` table already exists which contains `hospital name`,`longitude` & `latitude` values. On the basis of inputted `hospital name`, I want to retrieve its respective `latitude` & `longitude` values and map them on the next page displaying a google map.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You should be able to query your location table based on the input name (assuming all hospitals have unique names?), then output some javascript that calls the Maps API to plot to its latitude+longitude

Answer (score 0):

See Here : -> https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/346407/getting-latitude-and-longitude-info-into-text-boxes>

Find your Lat Long coordinates on Click and open it in new window.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database is either MS SQL or MySQL

The following SQL query uses [**Spherical Law of Cosines**](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to calculate the distance between a coordinate and coordinates in a table. It limits result to 10 and orders by distance.

> d = acos( sin(lat1).sin(lat2) + cos(lat1).cos(lat2).cos(lng2-lng1) ).R

Were R = earth’s radius (mean radius = 3,959 miles or 6,371km)

```
SELECT hospital name,latitude,longitude, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(center_latitude)) 
                      * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude)
                      - radians(center_longitude)) + sin(radians($center_latitude)) 
                      * sin( radians( latitude )))) AS distance FROM table 
                      ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Where `center_latitude` & `center_longitude` are coordinates of location.